# How to set the culture in a dotnetcore xunit test

Tags: c#, .net-core, cultureinfo, xunit

I have the following unit test that I'm porting from a .Net Framework library to .Net core xunint test library. The project the unit test needs to be added to is

https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid

and is being added to the selected file as show here

[image]

The unit test I'm trying to add is

```
[Test]
public void ParsingWithCommaDecimalSeparatorShouldWork()
{
    var ci = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)
             {
                 NumberFormat =
                 {
                     NumberDecimalSeparator = ","
                     , NumberGroupSeparator = "."
                 }
             };
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;

    var t = Template.Parse("{{2.5}}");
    var result = t.Render( new Hash(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
    Assert.AreEqual( result, "2.5"   );
}
```

However the test fails to compile in dotnet core.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'Thread' does not contain a definition for
>   'CurrentCulture' and no extension method 'CurrentCulture' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'Thread' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   DotLiquid.Tests(net451) C:\Users\phelan\workspace\dotliquid\src\DotLiquid.Tests\OutputTests.cs  113 N/A

I need to have different unit tests with different cultures. I would like to create an XUnit theory where each instance passes in a different culture for the unit test to verify against. How is this done in .NetCore?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I looked at some of the dotnet [source](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Globalization/CultureInfo.cs#L494) and I found this.

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = ci;
```

Basically it looks like you can set the default thread current culture from a static property of `CultureInfo` rather than from `Thread.CurrentThread`

poking around a bit more I found [this](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Threading/Thread.cs#L472)

```
public CultureInfo CurrentCulture
{
    get
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<CultureInfo>() != null);
        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    }

    set
    {
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        // If you add more pre-conditions to this method, check to see if you also need to 
        // add them to CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture.set.

        if (m_CurrentCulture == null && m_CurrentUICulture == null)
            nativeInitCultureAccessors();

        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = value;
    }
}
```

This is in `Thread.cs`.  So you can set the  `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` property explicitly.

example:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB"); ;

Assert.Equal("£1,000.00", String.Format("{0:C}", 1000));

CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US"); ;

Assert.Equal("$1,000.00", String.Format("{0:C}", 1000));
```

[image]

csproj file for unit test project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>

    <ApplicationIcon />

    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>

    <StartupObject />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.3.0-preview-20170425-07" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: but I *can* spin up new threads in the test case so the tip is worth a +1 even if it's not exactly the correct answer.

Comment: Fails at runtime ;)

Comment: I am running VS 2017 with Core 2.0 and the tests are passing (also passed in core 1.1)

Comment: Hmmm. Let me check. Sandbox is in a mess at the moment. I was sure I got some kind of exception when I tried it.

Comment: No I just get a build failure with dotnet core app 1.0 ( maybe with 2.0 ) this has been improved ?? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ahljp4bqjig3zkl/devenv_2017-09-13_17-23-16.png

Comment: According to the docs `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is read/write as of .Net Framework 4.6, and has always been in .NetCore.  Are you sure your project is targeting the correct framework?

Comment: Can please you post your csproj file so I can see what you have configured.

Comment: My Bad     <TargetFrameworks>net461;netcoreapp1.0</TargetFrameworks>
 upgraded from     <TargetFrameworks>net451;netcoreapp1.0</TargetFrameworks> works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154360/discussion-between-aaron-roberts-and-bradgonesurfing).

Comment: In the examples above the desired culture is obtained by creating a new instance. When you do not intend to modify this instance `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")` should be used, which gives you a read-only default.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = ci;
```

and **then** spin up a new thread. This will set the current culture for the next thread. The final test case is.

```
[Test]
public void ParsingWithCommaDecimalSeparatorShouldWork()
{
    var ci = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)
             {
                 NumberFormat =
                 {
                     NumberDecimalSeparator = ","
                     , NumberGroupSeparator = "."
                 }
             };

    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = ci;
    var result = "";
    var thread = new Thread
        ( delegate()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
            Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator);

            var t = Template.Parse("{{2.5}}");
            result = t.Render(new Hash(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        } );
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();
    Assert.AreEqual(result, "2.5");

}
```

which is a bit messy but get the job done.

Comment: You can try calling it from a ModuleInitializer:
    public static class MyInitializer
    {
        [ModuleInitializer]
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL");
        }
    }